# How to change the type of a particular row/cell from int to varchar

Tags: mysql

I have created a table in mysql. In the table I defined earlier a type int for "Phone number" but it's throwing an error while entering the phone number that: "ERROR 1265 (01000): Data truncated for column 'phone' at row 1".

So I tried to change the type of the field Phone from 'int' to 'varchar' but I am not able to change.

I know we can use ALTER command like I tried -
"ALTER TABLE student(table name) COLUMN MODIFY varchar"

However, it is modifying the type of whole column while I just want to change the type of a particular cell/row.

Comment: MySQL does not operate with "*cells*".  It has fields (columns) and rows of data.

Comment: `VARCHAR` = `VARCHAR(1)`.  Is that what you want???  If not define it properly.

Answer (score 1):

Use this commands.

```
USE dbname;
ALTER TABLE table1 CHANGE phonenumber phonenumber varchar(255);

or 

USE dbname;
ALTER TABLE table1 MODIFY phonenumber1 varchar(25);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below SQL ALTER statement to modify your column type as:

```
alter table cell_info modify nums varchar(20);
```

Example:
    create table cell_info(id int, nums int);
    insert into cell_info values(1,12341234);
    alter table cell_info modify nums varchar(20);
    insert into cell_info values(1,'My new number');

```
select * from cell_info;
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9d89f7/1)

Comment: In your case statement will look like:     alter table student modify phone varchar(20);

Comment: Thanks dude, its perfectly worked for me. ;)
And thanks for the demo too.

Comment: If info is useful then u may accept the answer and upvote